# An Issue To get a video file on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I published my website on azure (A Web API) which contains a video file. The problem is I can access to the image file, but I cannot to the .mp4 file and get the following error:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must update the `web.config` by adding the .mp4 mimetype to solve the issue:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```